# Aspose, append Pdf's without extra space

Tags: aspose

I've got list of Pdf objects (or Streams) and would like to append them that there wont be extra white space between them. Aspose 'PdfFileEditor.Concatenate' adds next Pdf starting from next page but I'd like to add it immediately after previous finishes.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that was possible (there wasn't much time) so had to refactor the code that only one stream was created with correct layout.